# How can I ask my closed question in a better manner?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I recently posted a question on SO and within minutes it was slammed shut offensively without any help as to how I could make it better. Furthermore, it got saddled with the 'subjective' tag, when if you read the whole description instead of just the question, it really wasn't subjective. What did I do wrong, and what can I do to not repeat this? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145083/what-is-your-favorite-net-interface-closed)

Edit: Pointers from TheTXI on the best way to ask a question:

- Make sure it isn't a duplicate
- Make sure the question you are asking has a potential "correct" answer
- Make your question clear and provide enough information for it to be possible for someone to actually help you
- Make sure it is programming (stackoverflow), sysadmin (serverfault), and computer (superuser) related.
- Make sure the title of the question is not subjective.

Comment: Thanks for the tag update Jeff.

Answer (score 3):

Anytime you ask something called "What is your favorite" it is going to get labeled as subjective (which is what it is, it is open to people's biases).

The best way to ask a qusetion:

- Make sure it isn't a duplicate
- Make sure the question you are asking has a potential "correct" answer
- Make your question clear and provide enough information for it to be possible for someone to actually help you
- Make sure it is programming (stackoverflow), sysadmin (serverfault), and computer (superuser) related.

Comment: I'm confused. Did you read the body of the question, or just the title? Maybe that is the problem, that the title is subjective, even though the question itself isn't. Other than that I did follow your pointers. I assumed it was a good question because the answers would be highly informative, and really it has as many correct answers as there are Interfaces in the CBL.

Answer (score 2):

Charles, you asked

> How can I ask my [closed] question in a better manner?

The answer is, "don't". This isn't a fan club, it's a Q&A site, in that case, about programming. A question on the most *useful* interface, or the most *misunderstood* interface, might fly. But the *favorite*?

Comment: John, I guess really the major misinterpretation here has been of the title of my question. I was not actually asking for a favorite interface. I was actually looking for a listing of interfaces that the community could share. I was really hoping that some people would jump on board and post some interfaces that they use in their daily coding, but that I never even knew existed.
This was one of my first questions, and I didn't realize that the community would be so shallow as to read only the title, I thought they would atleast descend into the question itself and offer some insight.

Comment: @Charles: I'm afraid there's also a bit of limited knowledge of .NET going on here. Do you have any idea how many interfaces there are in .NET? I'm afraid it's really a silly question even without the silly title.