# Endless nights of redirect loops for questions with titles where "closed" is in brackets

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, redirection

While reading through a question here on Meta, I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with) listed under the Related section. Gritting my teeth and clicking the link resulted in a whirlwind of redirects and an error in Google Chrome.

> The webpage at
>   [Please append the reason for closing to the title along with "Closed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with)
>   has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this
>   site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it
>   is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your
>   computer.

Visiting the URL directly has the same effect. Clearing cookies did not help.

The offending loopy title reads:

> Please append the reason for closing to the title along with "[closed]"

I've seen similar questions asked with regards to migrated questions, so perhaps this is a dupe, but I'm not sure. What might cause this?

I'm using Chrome 16.0.912.77

[image: Screenshot of endless 301 redirects]

Comment: Hum. Can't repro now, though could repro 28 mins ago.

Comment: Nah...same here. No-repro at the moment. Perhaps an update happened in the mean time?

Comment: It's something to do with having `"[closed]"` in the title. Robert Harvey changed it to `"closed"` to fix it

Comment: I feel like I should vote to close only so that I can find out who is the person who wants this well written bug report closed

Comment: @Koper It was I. With my massive fingers on my mobile phone I accidentally managed to vote to close (and confirm <-- yes, massive idiot) on my own question. :) But in any case [Robert Harvey confirmed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6982/please-append-the-reason-for-closing-to-the-title-along-with-closed) that the title was the cause of the problem. So it could be closed if he doesn't answer here.

Comment: Although I would of course like to see the answer/explanation.

Comment: Here's another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/how-can-i-ask-my-question-in-a-better-manner

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out that we had 5 questions on Meta and 6 question on Stack Overflow that were like `%[[]closed]%`.

We already have a sanity check that ensures you do not add the word `[closed]` to the title, turn out our redirect logic was tripping for legacy posts that were created prior to the sanity check.

I am pretty apprehensive of playing with any redirect logic, fixed the offending rows in the DB.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after such a long time, but perhaps you have some input: The same issue was brought up in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137526/questions-with-closed-in-the-middle-of-the-title-are-redirected-indefinitely) for another SE site. Is the editing procedure you have followed general practice (and should the question perhaps be asked on the SE's specific Meta) or it there any point in requesting a global SO/SE-wide fix?

Answer (score 7):

### Confirmed:

[image]

Chrome 16.0.912.77 m on Windows 8

Comment: A downvote for confirming a bug?

Comment: +1 For your help in confirming I've not lost my sanity. ;)

Comment: And a close vote on the question itself - odd indeed.  +1 from me.

Comment: @AdamRackis Don't worry. The (accidental) close vote was mine. See my comment above.

Comment: Maybe someone envy you for already using Windows 8? ;)