# Too many redirects when trying to open a specific question

Tags: bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Endless nights of redirect loops for questions with titles where “closed” is in brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121270/endless-nights-of-redirect-loops-for-questions-with-titles-where-closed-is-in)

When trying to open the question [Instead of {closed} for migrated questions, [migrated]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions), I get the HTTP 310 error message, also known as

> Eeeek! There were too many redirects.

Additional information:

- It only happens with this specific question.
- I've tried both logged in and as an anonymous user.
- I've tried Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Using W7 and Chrome, same thing happens for my account.

Comment: I don't get such an error message on Firefox. I get "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I might have been unclear. It's a HTTP 310 error.

Comment: repos on chrome 16.0.912.77 ubuntu 10.4... yukky..

Comment: Reproduced on Android 2.1 browser.

Comment: @random: Duplicate? My question has "closed" in **curly** brackets. :-P

Comment: It's the migrated part at the end which is the same cause

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a known issue, but was never fixed because editing every single question with this issue is apparently less trouble. You can still access them by [manually correcting the slug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated).

Comment: We know about this and are looking at a sane way to fix it.  Canonical urls are pretty important to [search engines](http://google.com) :)

Comment: The last of these should now be resolved.