# Questions with closed in the middle of the title are redirected indefinitely

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Endless nights of redirect loops for questions with titles where “closed” is in brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121270/endless-nights-of-redirect-loops-for-questions-with-titles-where-closed-is-in)

Questions with [closed] in the titles can't be reliably opened.

This question in Ask Ubuntu couldn't be opened because of the reason:

- [Are the questions with the mark (closed) erased?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/624/are-the-questions-with-the-mark-erased)

The title of the question read:

> are the questions with the mark [closed] erased?

I sort of managed to work around this by stuffing in a closed in the middle of the link and it worked.

The URL that actually worked is

- [Are the questions with the mark (closed) erased?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/624/are-the-questions-with-the-mark-erased)

Can we not arbitrary remove [closed] from the URL if it doesn't exist at the end?

---

I probably realize this wasn't the case at the beginning. Because currently if the question title has [closed], it can't be submitted.

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - title can't include the closed marker.

Comment: @Bart While apparently this question is a dupe of that, the devs have not fixed the problem for other sites. I would be more than happy if they do at once.

Comment: Nor was it really fixed for Meta SO as I understand (due to tricky redirect logic), but the database entries for the offending questions were edited.

Comment: This wasn't fixed when closed as a dupe - it is now correctly resolved.